# Dart/Flutter: Split string every nth character?

Tags: string, list, flutter, dart, split

I have a single string made up of two digit numbers with leading zeros
(ie *'0102031522'*)

that I want to split into a list as integers without the leading zeros.

Output of this example should be `[1,2,3,15,22]`.

I'm having trouble trying to get this converted as Dart is new to me, and i have no clue where to start. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For any size split and making a list.

```
void main() {
  final splitSize = 2;
  RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"\d{"+"$splitSize"+"}");
  String str = "0102031522";
  Iterable<Match> matches = exp.allMatches(str);
  var list = matches.map((m) => int.tryParse(m.group(0)));
  print(list);
}
```

Tested on dartpad

Comment: Thank you @Doc. I'm trying to make this work, but it's just producing the numbers, not in a list. How do I put them in a list of integers like `[1,2,3,15,22]`?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!